# What is this woody plant with spicy, citrus flavored twigs?

Tags: identification, trees

I was out hiking today, and, as I often do, I absentmindedly chewed on twigs that I broke off from around shoulder height. I noticed that one twig had a spicy, citrus flavor. It reminded me of mandarin orange. Unfortunately, I had walked away from the plant I took the twig from before I noticed the taste. I saved a bit of the twig, and I took a picture of it. I live in Connecticut. Can anybody help me identify the plant?

[image: Connecticut Twig]

Answer (score 6):

It could have been [sassafras (*Sassafras albidum*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sassafras). All parts of the plant are aromatic and spicy. This citrusy quality has made it popular as a culinary flavoring, but the [essential oil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_oil), which contains a [phenylpropene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenylpropene) called [safrole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safrole), has [been found](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10496370) to be a weak [hepatocarcinogen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepatocellular_carcinoma) in rats. Thus culinary sassafras oil is now for the most part devoid of safrole.

Also, the bark, color (interior and exterior) looks right, as well as the branching habit. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yWP0.jpg) the range map. Pictures:

[image]
   [image]
   [image]

[image]